# Ubuntu 20.04 LAN network problem

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, teamviewer

Error log:

[image: This is the error log]

I have a dual boot desktop system Window and Ubuntu 20.04. I deleted Ubuntu 18.04 which was working fine and installed (not upgraded) to Ubuntu 20.04. Everything was fine, but later I got several problems. I lose the LAN network connect every night. when I go to the office I close the network connection and start it and it works fine for several hours and something still works for days. In the beginning the network always showed a question mark on it. Now it does not show anything and internet connection drops.

I installed caffeine so that the PC does not go to sleep and I removed the screen server in the power section.

I am not sure if anybody has this problem with Ubuntu 20.04.

I also have a problem with TeamViewer with Ubuntu. Every time I switch off the display I can not longer use TeamViewer.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator Hi I got an error '<error> [1606315511.1371] dhcp4 (eno1): error -111 dispatching events'

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NetworkManager[1108] <error> [1606315511.1371] dhcp4 (eno1): error -111 dispatching events
> ```

This seems to be a bug in network manager's `dhcp4` client.  It has been resolved upstream [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/commit/c5d1d4c498c50dfc7d2d18b213a117dd1199f1de).

Make sure your software is up to date, it is likely that this issue would have been integrated into a dot release in the meantime.

If you are up to date and still have the same issue, please log a bug against Ubuntu to ensure the patch gets integrated into 20.04.

This [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1817788#c0) includes the following workaround:

> Just add
>
> ```
> [main]
> dhcp=dhclient
> ```
>
> into NM's configuration (/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/use-dhclient.conf for example), and then restart NetworkManager.service.